# Can we add the main method in class after creating the class without main method in eclipse?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Can we add the main method in class after creating the class without main method in eclipse?

I created a class and am trying to add main method after creation, it is not picking up.

> > Error: Editor does not contain a main type,

Comment: Please show your code for the main class, then some help can be given

Comment: Yes you can. What is the error you are getting. If its not running please build the project and test.

Comment: Yes you can.  Tell what type of compile or run time error generated

Comment: Editor does not contain a main type, Even after I cleaned and Build the project

Comment: The main method is like any other method, therefore you can simply add it yourself in the class body.

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to insert the `main` method in the wrong place? Please try with a very small class, and if it doesn’t work, edit the question and paste the full source code of the class with the added `main` method.

Comment: In Eclipse, if you have not changed this preference, you can type `main` and hit CTRL-<space>, and Eclipse will insert a correct main method for you — just pick `main - main method` from the list it presents. If this doesn’t work either, there’s something else wrong.

Comment: Be more specific in question eg. What type of error given,  show full class what u have done so far.  Otherwise it doesn't make any sense

Comment: I have added the error in Description. Not sure what happened but after restart of my eclipse it worked. Thanks all

Comment: Great that you got it to work. Allow me to suggest you delete the now obsolete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kalyan-chavali, Could you please share code so that we get more details. As it's working for me ..

```
public class HelloWorld {
    private static void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Say Hi");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Say Hello World");
        sayHi();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Type this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
}
```

Comment: added and build , Still I'm getting this error: Editor does not contain a main type

Comment: @kalyanchavali Go to Run>Run As>Java Aplication. Sometimes eclipse does not create the run configuration if there isnt a main method. Doing what i recomended above is essentially telling eclipse to re-try running the aplication being asured that there will be a main method ;)

Comment: No it didn't work

Comment: Can you show us your code?